# How do I save a file path in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

When I go to save my file path in my database I do

```
INSERT INTO `cars`(`carID`, `carType`, `carModel`, `carYear`, `carBrand`, `carImage`, `carPrice`) VALUES (1, 'electric', 'LEAF', '2019', 'Nissan', '\img\Hybrids\Leaf\White\Side.jpg', '29,990')
```

Then when I retrieve the data from the database it returns the file path as 
imgHybridsLeafWhiteSide.jpg
how do I fix the file path to return  \img\Hybrids\Leaf\White\Side.jpg

Comment: Use ` \\ ` or ` / `

Comment: it depends which function you use to retrieve data, looks like `\\` is not properly escaped in your code, but solution is depending on details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape your backslash (use `\\` or `/`):

```
INSERT INTO `cars`(`carID`, `carType`, `carModel`, `carYear`, `carBrand`, `carImage`, `carPrice`) VALUES (1, 'electric', 'LEAF', '2019', 'Nissan', '\\img\\Hybrids\\Leaf\\White\\Side.jpg', '29,990')
```

You can use PDO to safely insert values into the database.

```
$db   = new PDO( $dsn, $username, $password );
$carImage = "\img\Hybrids\Leaf\White\Side.jpg";
$sql  = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO cars (carImage) VALUES(:carImage)");
$sql->bindParam(:carImage, $carImage, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();
```

Comment: Double quotes are a bad idea here since `"\n"` and `'\n'` are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the data variables as strings before the insert occurs then use a prepared statement to create the record. *Forward slashes for file navigation.

```
<?php
// Data variables
$carID = "1";
$carType = "electric";
$carModel = "LEAF";
$carYear = "2019"; // this column should be set to int as the year is a whole number
$carBrand = "Nissan";
$carImage = "/img/Hybrids/Leaf/White/Side.jpg"; // This column should be set to text so the slashes can be stored
$carPrice = "29990"; // This column should be set to float(7,2) which allows a max of 9999999.99

//Insert
$insert = mysqli_prepare($con, "insert into cars (carID,carType,carModel,carYear,carBrand,carImage,carPrice) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($insert, "sssssss", $carID,$carType,$carModel,$carYear,$carBrand,$carImage,$carPrice);
mysqli_stmt_execute($insert);
?>
```

Comment: Right on for prepared statements, but go one further: Use the object-oriented interface. That's way less code.

Comment: Thanks. I'm all for less code. I'm looking into that right now :)

Comment: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($insert, ...)` becomes `$insert->bind_param(...)` which is way easier to follow.

Comment: That's looks much tidier, I'm still at the beginning stage of a new project so I should def take advantage of that. By the looks of it I may be able to condense my code by 50%?

Comment: For `mysqli` it's the only way to go, plus you avoid mistakes like inadvertently using `mysql_query`. To be honest, if you're just getting started use PDO instead. It's way more effective because of things like named placeholders which can save a ton of time. You can basically skip the bind step and just `execute([ 'a' => $a, ... ])`.